# Change (update) text in Python Tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am trying to update information in tkinter labels and buttons without redrawing entire screens. I'm using Python 3, a Raspberry Pi, and Idle. I have a trivial example of what I am trying to do. I see comments here that suggest I need to learn to manipulate stringvariable or IntVar, etc. but my book is totally unhelpful in that regard. In this example, I would like the number between the buttons to track the value of the number as it changes with button pushes.

```
##MoreOrLess.01.py
from tkinter import *  

global number
number = 5

root = Tk()
root.title("Test Buttons")

def Less():
    global number
    number -= 1
    print ("The number is now ", number)

def More():
    global number
    number += 1
    print("The number is now ", number)

def MakeLabel(number):
    textvariable = number
    label1 = Label(root, text = "Pick a button please.").pack(pady=10)
    btnL = Button(root, text = "More", command = More).pack(side = LEFT)  
    btnR = Button(root, text = "Less", command = Less).pack(side = RIGHT)
    label2 = Label(root, text = number).pack(pady = 20)

MakeLabel(number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you base yourself in a book, check the official [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) of tkinter. in your case you must create a variable of type [`IntVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) with its `set()` and `get()` method, and when you want to link that variable through [`textvariable`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm).

```
from tkinter import *  

root = Tk()
root.title("Test Buttons")

number = IntVar()
number.set(5)

def Less():
    number.set(number.get() - 1)
    print ("The number is now ", number.get())

def More():
    number.set(number.get() + 1)
    print("The number is now ", number.get())

def MakeLabel(number):
    textvariable = number
    label1 = Label(root, text = "Pick a button please.").pack(pady=10)
    btnL = Button(root, text = "More", command = More).pack(side = LEFT)  
    btnR = Button(root, text = "Less", command = Less).pack(side = RIGHT)
    label2 = Label(root, textvariable = number).pack(pady = 20)

MakeLabel(number)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note: you don't _have_ to use an `IntVar`. It's quite possible to set the values of the widget without it.

Comment: Thank you, you make it look so EASY! This really helps.

Comment: @Gortoon If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour] :D